# Using reduce({}) to create nested hash to calculate averages, rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, metadata

I have a controller which looks like this:

```
  def index
   collection = Chart.all
   render json: collection, meta: {averages: collection.averages }
  end
```

So as you can see, what I'm trying to do is a regular GET to an Index method, which has a `meta` object, which returns "averages".

`Chart` belongs to an `employee` , and an employee has many `areas`. Chart also has many `chart_axis_values`. Each `chart_axis_value` has a `.value` (float) and a `.name`(string).

`chart_axis_values` are things like "motivation", "satisfaction", "positivity" and "collaboration". Each of them has a value(float), which we will use to calculate the average of each `chart_axis_value` in all Charts.

So, as you can see, an employee has a Chart, in which he has these 'axes', and each axis has a value.

Say I have 5 Charts, from 5 different employees, and each employee belongs to a different 'Area' in the company (HHRR, Marketing, Technology, etc...). When I make a GET request to get Index of Charts, I need to receive all 5 charts, each of them with their axes, and each axis has it's name and value. And in the "meta" object, I need to receive the average `value` for each `chart_axis_value`. So I will count how many times an axis appears(with it's name), and I will accumulate the values of each axis, and when I finish the GET request, I will calculate `total_count/total_sum` for each axis. All this will be returned in the JSON format, so I will be using a hash.

All this problem is solved, I already have the averages for each axis, but now I have a new problem.

Each employee has_many (zero or more) Areas, and when I do my get request, instead of getting all charts from all employees, I can filter by one or more Areas and only get the Charts of those employees that belong to a specific Area(or more, if I filter by more than one Area).

So what I want to do now is I want to receive, `averages` values for each `Area`. So I will be doing the same "counting" of times an axis appeared, and the same accumulation of the value of this axis, but I will be doing this for each area, so I can calculate the average for each Area.

Here's what I have so far.

```
## /models/chart.rb
class Chart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  has_many :chart_axis_values

  def self.averages ## Method for the meta in the controller

    # first we generate a hash with the total sum and total objects
    values = all.reduce({}) do |values, chart|
      # we iterate over each axis
      chart.chart_axis_values.each do |axis|
        # ignore nils
        unless axis.value.nil?

          # first we define hash to keep count and total sum
          values[axis.slug] ||= {count: 0, total: 0.0}

          # We count and accumulate for each axis, so later on we calculate the average
          values[axis.slug][:count] += 1
          values[axis.slug][:total] += axis.value
        end
      end
      values
    end
    # once we have the total we transform the hash calculating averages
    values.each_with_object({}) do |(axis, values), averages|
      averages[axis] = values[:total]/values[:count]
    end
  end
end
```

This way, I get the averages for each axis. Now I'm trying to do the same, but once for each Area, and I'm having lots of trouble on how to solve this. I was hoping someone here would look at my problem and maybe suggest a solution, or come up with something I can use and understand. I think my problem is very specific, so I understand if don't have the time to help me, but it's worth the try! As of now, I think I have to do something like this:

```
## /models/chart.rb
class Chart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  has_many :chart_axis_values

  def self.averages ## Method for the meta in the controller

    # first we generate a hash with the total sum and total objects
    values = all.reduce({}) do |values, chart|
      # we iterate over each axis
      chart.chart_axis_values.each do |axis|
        # ignore nils
        unless axis.value.nil?
          chart.employee.areas.each do |area|

            # first we define hash to keep count and total sum
            values[area.name] ||= {axis.name=>{count: 0, total: 0.0}}

            if values[area.name][axis.name].nil?
              values[area.name].merge({axis.name=>{count: 0, total: 0.0}})
            end

            # We count and accumulate for each axis, so later on we calculate the average
            values[area.name][axis.name][:count] += 1
            values[area.name][axis.name][:total] += axis.value
          end
        end
      end
      values
    end
    # once we have the total we transform the hash calculating averages
    values.each_with_object({}) do |(axis, values), averages|
      averages[axis] = values[:total]/values[:count]
    end
  end
end
```

And that's as far as I got without turning the code into Frankenstein and making it stop making sense.

I've spent days on this problem, and I just can't seem to get it to work, I'm getting so frustrated, any help or suggestion will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Doing this in Ruby for every request is most likely going to be horribly ineffecient. Can you leverage the database instead to select averages? I would consider creating a materialized view in your database.

Comment: Hey @max, thank you for your suggestion. I see what you mean, i hadn't thought about it, i'll try and calculate averages using the SQL approach you suggest, seems a lot more  efficient. I'll look into how to write the SQL query properly and hopefully use Arel for this. Thank you for the help.